# Loading Ubuntu on re-built computer

Tags: system-installation, vga

I'm trying to re-built an old desktop I got hold of.  There was no HDD so I added an SSD.  I have my USB key with Ubuntu iso file.  Keyboard powering through USB, but my first challenge is that screen does not display video.  Power is on (suggests no VGA input).  I've taken out the RAM and the small battery.  But still no VGA input. VGA connectors have been checked, so I guess it should be working? Thanks for tips and advice.

Comment: What happens when you boot ? do you get to the bios ? grub / boot menu ?